# TypeError: show is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery for a dynamic content behavior on a website. I've got an error:

> TypeError: $("#id").attr("src",
>   thisContent.attr("data-attr")).show is not a function

Firstly I thought that it was browser related, but it turns out that it isn't. The error is on this line:

```
$('#id').attr('src', thisContent.attr('data-attr')).show();
```

Comment: `var thisContent = $(this).find('.content');`

Comment: seems fire-fox version problem only

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: Try changing `$` to `jQuery` and see if the problem persists. I've seen cases where the **Firebug extension** (which uses the `$` as it's selector) would simply overwrite jQuery's shorthand. Though I wasn't able to deduce the exact cause of this. Just a thought.

Comment: try using `jQuery` instead of `$` ... I think that works over compatibility issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the second argument of `.attr()` is `undefined` the getter will be invoked.
Seems like the getter is invoked instead of the setter.

Getter:

```
$(...).attr(String) // returns String which has no method .show()
```

Setter:

```
$(...).attr(String, String) // returns jQuery object, which has method .show()
```

`thisContent.attr('data-attr')` might return `undefined` in some cases, and therefor the getter gets invoked instead of the desired setter method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

Rename your data-attr to something else.

see if data-attr exists inside thisContect.attr.

Log the following line and go to the Console. There you will see the data-attr does not exist or is at the wrong place.

console.log(thisContent);

Answer (score 0):

Random question, but to be sure...

Are you accessing jQuery via their CDN?

If you are, do both machines load the jQuery code in ok? Both can see the CDN with no issues (both connected to the internet)? and other bits of jQuery code are working?

It's very rare that a browser would have a difference in the way it renders/handles JS as it is such a well established language. So my suggestion is, rather than being a browser based issue, it's something outside of your code.

Just an idea..